# im working on arrays in python, a term called type array class confused me

Tags: arrays, python-3.x

So in my lab manual there is a task to make a function that takes 2 arrays as parameters both of **type array class** and returns the sum of them. Now im really confused with the words "type array class"

```
class Array:
    def __init__(self,cols,rows):
        self.cols = cols
        self.rows = rows
        self.arr1 = [[0 for i in range(cols)]for i in range(rows)]

    def addvalues(self,array1, array2):
        arrayadd = []
        for i, j in zip(array1, array2):
            arrayadd.append([m + n for m, n in zip(i, j)])
        return arrayadd
```

Comment: I guess it's just so you know what kind of values are passed to your function as there is (afaik) no way to limit the values passed in as param

Comment: Can you quote the section from the manual? A „type array class“ is a bit like a „car Nissan automobile“. Note that an „array typeclass“ would be something entirely different. Is the code from the manual? It appears to be a matrix rather than an array.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi "Add a function AddValues() that takes two parameters array1 and array2 (both of type
of Array class) and returns a matrix (Array class) containing sum of two given matrices"

Answer (score 0):

**After reading your comment**

Its saying that the class type (or technically instance) of the 2 parameters should be array. isinstance(array1, Array) should evaluate to true. 
checkout https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/type-isinstance-python/ for more on types and instances.